# How do I allow CakePHP to return a different home page based on auth/logged in status?

Tags: cakephp, authentication, routes

I am looking for the best way to return the home page of an application based on whether a user is currently logged in or not.

It appears that `beforeFilter`'s `allow()` functionality could help this, but it does look like this function will redirect the user.

Rather, I would prefer a specific controller (for example, to display a 'Home' view for a User model) display if a user is logged in, but return a static home page for non-logged in users. There shouldn't be any redirect required as they would be display using the same URL request.

Is there a standard way of doing this? I also reasoned that perhaps I could modify `routes.php` with conditionals, but **AuthComponent** is not available at this stage of the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a route pointing to your controller action, lets say OverviewController:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'overview', 'action' => 'homepage'));
```

Then you switch inside this action dynamically:

```
if (!($uid = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id'))) {
    return $this->render('some_action');
    //or return $this->render('/Pages/some_static_page');
}
// normal homepage action for $uid xyz
```

Comment: Thanks @mark, this worked. Though, I am still a bit hesitant to use the solution as it doesn't process the controller for this alternate view. Currently the alternative view is a static page, but anything beyond this and it seems like the solution wouldn't work correctly. (and it feels incorrect to include a potentially sizable amount of logic within the conditional of the original controller action's function).

Comment: you do realize that it is up to you how far the controller code is executed before actually branching and rendering a different view, don't you? you could also do that at the very end of the action - leaving you all the possibilities in the world.
so, yes, it would always work correctly if you use it wisely.
I also dont see a "potentially sizable amount of logic" in a single if statement..^^

Answer (score 1):

Using AuthComponent means that you don't need to worry about the `login()` action in your UsersController (I believe this is the default setup). However, if you put some code in that method, you can have it do whatever you want:

```
// In users_controller.php
function login()
{   
  if ( $this->Auth->user() ) { 
    if ( $this->Auth->user('role') == USER_ROLE_ADMIN ) { 
      $this->redirect('/admin');
    } else {
      $this->redirect('/');
    }   
  }   
}
```

Note the line that checks the user role and redirects appropriately. Also important is the outermost if statement (`if ( $this->Auth->user() )`), this will only execute the code inside if the user has successfully logged in.

Comment: Thanks @regulatethis but it is not really what I am looking for. The output must be on the same URL (essentially, the root of a domain, no redirecting), but returning a different view (from a different model) if you are logged in as opposed to viewing the page as a logged out user.

Comment: So why not just have an if statement in this view/controller that displays content based on whether the user is logged in or not?

Comment: I could, but, especially considering the logged in view and the logged out views are part of different controllers/models, it really seems like the incorrect, non-MVC, way to go about the process.

Comment: @Rhys I can't see an actual problem. Your controllers set up views and render different ones based on all sorts of factors, why is this any different?